# Datepicker UI display in block, the right line far apart from datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I found out that when the datepicker display in block, the outter right grey line display far apart from the datepicker.

I did tried add  to control but did not help at all.

Thanks

Here is the sample code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#datepicker").datepicker( {
            dateFormat: "dd M yy",
            numberOfMonths: [2,1]});

    });
</script>

<body>
    <div id="datepicker"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Move the datepicker outline]

Comment: Could you please check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Datepickers don't have borders around them by default.

You can add one if you'd like by targeting `.ui-datepicker-group`:

```
.ui-datepicker-group {
  border: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
}
```

I've created a fiddle showcasing this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/v339g7yj/1/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for suggestion.
In your fiddle, did you see the grey line (the outline), which not around the datepicker?

Comment: Yes -- the grey line is not there because you are displaying more than one calendar month in a single `datepicker()`. You need to manually add the border in yourself. I have however just updated this to be light grey instead of black :)

Comment: I have edit my post and attach an image to avoid any confusion.
Thank for the suggestion but it not fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

To change the border of datepicker try this.

```css
.ui-datepicker-group {   
   border: 1px solid #555;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
 }
```

```html
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#datepicker").datepicker( {
            dateFormat: "dd M yy",
            numberOfMonths: [2,1]});

    });
</script>

<body>
    <div id="datepicker"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix. Using CSS border and width will solve it.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#datepicker").datepicker( {
            dateFormat: "dd M yy",
            numberOfMonths: [2,1]});

    });
</script>
<style>

     #datepicker{/*USE THIS CSS STYLE THIS WILL SOLVE THE PROBLEM*/
        border:1px solid #999;
        width:195px;
     }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="datepicker"></div>
</body>
</html>
```